# Using ownCloud/Nextcloud with S3 bucket sync issues

Tags: amazon-s3, owncloud, nextcloud

I have included an S3 bucket to my Nextcloud instance as an external source, but not as a primary source. All files that appear on S3 appear as expected on Nextcloud. I can manually upload a file to the bucket which will also immediately appear in Nextcloud.

However, when I upload files to the S3 bucket via the API, the file does not show up in Nextcloud. It seems that there's no differences in permissions and ownership so I'm not sure what's happening.

It's all pretty straight forward so I can't see that I've missed anything and I don't know if I should be looking at Nextcloud or S3 as the culprit.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I've had no response on this. Can anyone supply some ideas about where to start looking for what the cause might be?

Comment: you might want to take a look at https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/26819 to see if it relates.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is [finally a patch merged](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/pull/14913) into the upcoming version. For the impatient, some people came up with work-arounds in the [Nextcloud issue tracker](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/6954).